Adding values from one dictionary to another
dict_1 = {1: {2}, 2: {3}, 3: {4}, 4: {11}}

dict_2 = {1: {2}, 2: {1}, 3: {4}, 4: {1,3}}

to get:
dict_1 = {1: {2}, 2: {3,1}, 3: {4}, 4: {11,1,3}}

How would I add the values from dict_2 in dict_1 without deleting the ones already there? I can add them as a list but for some reason, I get the error list unhashable when trying to add them:
to_add = set()
 for x in dict_2:
  if x in dict_1.keys():
  to_add.add(dict_1[x])
  to_add.add(dict_2[x])
  dict_1[x] = to_add


You could use a set.union within a dict comprehension
>>> {k: dict_1[k] | dict_2[k] for k in dict_1}
{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {4}, 4: {3, 1, 11}}

This assumes the dicts share identical keys, otherwise you could tweak the logic a little bit depending on your expectation if one dict has keys the other does not have. If you essentially want to merge the dicts so all possible keys are present then you would do something like
>>> dict_1 = {1: {2}, 2: {3}, 3: {4}, 4: {11}, 5: {10, 12}}
>>> dict_2 = {1: {2}, 2: {1}, 3: {4}, 4: {1,3}, 6: {1, 2}}
>>> {k: dict_1.get(k, set()) | dict_2.get(k, set()) for k in dict_1 | dict_2}
{1: {2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {4}, 4: {3, 1, 11}, 5: {10, 12}, 6: {1, 2}}


dict_1 = {1: {2}, 2: {3}, 3: {4}, 4: {11}}
dict_2 = {1: {2}, 2: {1}, 3: {4}, 4: {1, 3}}

for key, value in dict_2.items():
    if key in dict_1:
        dict_1[key].update(value)
    else:
        dict_1[key] = value

This should work

dict_1 = {1: {2}, 2: {3}, 3: {4}, 4: {11}}
dict_2 = {1: {2}, 2: {1}, 3: {4}, 4: {1,3}}

dict_3 = {k:{*set(list(dict_1[k])+list(dict_2[k]))} for k in  dict_1.keys() | dict_2.keys()}


A bit of an explanation should be much helpful
